# Páginas Web - Mostrar, imputar e pesquisar dados em um arquivo Excel

Tags: javascript, html, json, microsoft-excel, sharepoint

Criei uma página *WEB* para funcionar como um *FAQ* no **SharePoint 2010**. Porém eu não tenho muito conhecimento nem no **SharePoint** e nem de `HTML` e `JavaScript`. Estou pesquisando para adquirir mais conhecimento sobre os temas. Na minha página eu criei o formulário para receber as perguntas e também o espaço onde será mostrado os resultados. Preciso fazer com que as perguntas sejam salvas numa planilha *Excel* no próprio **SharePoint** (solução temporária até que eu adquira conhecimento suficiente para fazer uma solução mais sofisticada e correta).

Posteriormente, quando as perguntas estiverem sido respondidas, é claro, preciso pesquisar essas perguntas e mostrar na tela para o usuário. Como eu disse, tenho pouco conhecimento no assunto.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse problema?

OBS.: Se alguém souber de um curso online de `JavaScript`, `HTML`, `JSON` e `CSS` para iniciantes e puderem compartilhar o link aqui eu agradeceria muito também.